# Multiple queries being generated when entire element selected with efcore

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

EF is producing multiple queries (n+1) instead of a single query with a subquery when the selection contains the entire element instead of just part of it.

Set up a project as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db?tabs=visual-studio

`context.Blogs.Select(a => new { a.Url, a.Posts.Count }).ToList();` runs this

`SELECT [a].[Url], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Posts] AS [p]
    WHERE [a].[BlogId] = [p].[BlogId]
) AS [Count]
FROM [Blogs] AS [a]`

But

`context.Blogs.Select(a => new { a, a.Posts.Count }).ToList();` runs this

`SELECT [a].[BlogId], [a].[Url]
FROM [Blogs] AS [a];`

`exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Posts] AS [p0]
WHERE @_outer_BlogId = [p0].[BlogId]',N'@_outer_BlogId int',@_outer_BlogId=2`

How can I rework the linq to select the entire Blog object without generating multiple queries?  Using include isn't helping from what i can see.

Comment: I just tried this through linqpad. The sql on linqpad and sql profiler both completed one sql query.

Comment: Maybe it works in asp.net but not core, I tested it thourally using built in sql server localdb and npgsql with local postgres. Both behave the same.

Comment: I'm afraid this is a defect of the current EF Core query translation/processing which probably will be fixed in some future version. The only way to workaround it AFAIK is to use `new` and assign all properties, e.g. `a => new { a = new Blog { BlogId = a.BlogId, Url = a.Url /*, … same for all Blog properties */ }, a.Posts.Count }`

Comment: @IvanStoev is correct in terms of EF Core. I also tried your query through EF Core and it produced multiple sql statements as you queried.

Comment: Actually there’s another way around it, using a link like a = Blog.BlogProperties.Blog... that works and gives u the blog with all properties in a single query... but adds extra joins to the query.